# How do I change the color of matched words in the command palette?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I change the color of the matched text in the result list of the command palette dropdown? I cannot see the word "Debug" since it has the same color as the blue bar.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

workbench.colorCustomizations -> quickInputList.focusBackground, hope it helpes someone.

Answer (score 0):

The following changes the color of the matched text:

```
workbench.colorCustomizations -> list.highlightForeground
```